Angular 18 application breaks after request on locahost
I've updated my Angular app to 18 version. I'm behind a corporate proxy, with my proxy file looking like this:
let proxyConfig = {
  '/test/**': {
    target: 'https://myUrl/test',
    secure: true,
    changeOrigin: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pathRewrite: { '^/test': '' },
  }

function setupForCorporateProxy(proxyConfig) {
  const proxyServer = process.env.http_proxy || process.env.HTTP_PROXY;
  if (proxyServer) {
    const agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxyServer);
    Object.keys(proxyConfig).forEach(function (key) {
      proxyConfig[key].agent = agent;
    });
  }
  return proxyConfig;
}

module.exports = setupForCorporateProxy(proxyConfig);

After the update, every request is failing on localhost. Still, for the GET request I found a solution by adding two ** instead of one * in the proxy configuration. Anyway, any POST/PUT/DELETE request is breaking the app with this error:
node:_http_outgoing:659
throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ClientRequest.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:659:11)
    at setOriginHeader (file:///myPath/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-C1-ZB6nQ.js:61834:16)
    at ProxyServer.<anonymous> (file:///myPath/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-C1-ZB6nQ.js:61887:7)
    at ProxyServer.emit (file:///myPath/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-C1-ZB6nQ.js:59914:36)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///myPath/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-C1-ZB6nQ.js:61332:16)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:531:35)
    at tickOnSocket (node:_http_client:839:7)
    at onSocketNT (node:_http_client:902:5)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
Node.js v20.15.0

What could be the issue? Seems very strange, because the update was fine, but it broke the proxy config.

angular has built-in support for proxies, why are you doing it by hand ?

Hi. Do you refer to the function setupForCorporateProxy?

That's litteraly your only bit of code, so yes ...
